# Uploading Tasmota to Water Heater

Tags: home-assistant, tasmota

I wish to use a new smart water heater with Tasmota[image: shown].

MCU is `TYWE3S`, and it has a ready made tutorial which was carried out as planned. Installation succeeded.[image: flahing].

*BUT* after flahing and assmbling it all back:

1. front panel works regardless tasmota is now installed (colors, timeouts and on/ off button + hearing the relay latches),
2. It seems Tasmota is not controlling anything (any GPIO assigned as `relay` did'nt operate the relay remotely).
3. Assembeld [image: pic1] [image: pic].

I'll appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: the second picture shows sloppy workmanship ... the green wire could easily short out parts of the circuit

Comment: @jsotola yes. I'll pay more attention next time. Thank you

Comment: please be very, very careful ... the circuit board could have power line voltages on it

Comment: @jsotola I\m guessing that send an ON request is via I2C. what do you think ?

Comment: @jsotola I\m guessing that send an ON request is via I2C. what do you think ?

Comment: no idea ... you did not say what you did

Comment: only flashed tasmota

Comment: what's the added wiring? ... there is nothing said about its purpose

Comment: @jsotola flashing Tasmota. It was taken off right away/

Comment: how do you know that Tasmota is actually installed?